# Emacs helm: Adding new sources to helm-mini

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, emacs-helm

Helm has builtin `helm-mini` command which includes `buffers` and `recentf` in its sources.

```
(setq helm-source-buffers-list
      (helm-make-source "Buffers" 'helm-source-buffers)))
(helm :sources helm-mini-default-sources
      :buffer "*helm mini*"
      :truncate-lines t)
```

There is one more package helm recent dirs which provides helm interface to `recentd`
It uses `'(helm-source-dired-recent-dirs)` as it source.

I am trying to combine those two so i am adding this in helm-mini

```
(append helm-mini-default-sources '(helm-source-dired-recent-dirs))
```

but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `append` form doesn't change the value of `helm-mini-default-sources`, so it, i.e., <kbd>M-x helm-mini</kbd>, does not work. You can combine `setq` and `append` or just `add-to-list`:

```lisp
(setq helm-mini-default-sources
      (append helm-mini-default-sources'(helm-source-dired-recent-dirs)))
;; or
(add-to-list 'helm-mini-default-sources 'helm-source-dired-recent-dirs 'append)
```

but the more flexible way is just using a plain `setq` because you can choose source and their order:

```lisp
(setq helm-mini-default-sources '(helm-source-buffers-list
                                  helm-source-dired-recent-dirs
                                  helm-source-recentf
                                  helm-source-buffer-not-found))
```

There is no needs to write your own `helm-mini` function, use the built-in one is enough.

Comment: initially, if `helm-source-dired-recent-dirs` is empty; then helm-mini throws error?

Comment: Use `(require 'helm-dired-recent-dirs)` to introduce the variable `helm-source-dired-recent-dirs` before using `helm-mini`, you should add it to your Emacs conf.